# Connecting to Database through functions and external files

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am simply trying to connect to my database by requiring another file with the connection function in it. I have tried numerous approaches but I always either get a blank page or my message 'failed execution'. Would appreciate someone pointing out where I am going wrong. Thanks.

```
config.php

define('DB_HOST','host');   //DATABASE HOST
define('DB_USERNAME','username');   //DATABASE USERNAME
define('DB_PASSWORD','password');   //DATABSE PASSWORD
define('DB_NAME','name');   //DATABASE NAME

function connectDB(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if(!$mysqli){
    trigger_error ('Avon Maitland Schools Canada could not establish a connection to the database at this time. Please try again later or contact info@yourschoolsincanada.com to inquire about this issue.'.mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    return $mysqli;
    }
}
```

And then my register file

```
register.php

require_once('includes/config.php');
$db_connection = connectDB();

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    /*ALL MY POSTING OF VARIABLE AND VALIDATION IS HERE BUT NOT THE ISSUE*/

    $sql = ("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password_1) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    //Prepare our query
    $stmt = $db_connection->prepare($sql) or die("Failed Execution");

    //Can not proceed if we can not prepare the query
    if(false===$stmt){
        die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
}   
    //Bind the fields and there paramters to our query in our testing variable $next_step
    $next_step = $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $db_pass);

    //If next_step is false then it didn't work and there is no sense of proceeding
    if($false===$next_step){
        die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));
}   

    //Place the Execute into a variable and test if it executed or not
    $next_step = $stmt->execute();
    //If next_step is false then it didn't work and there is no sense of proceeding 
    if(false===$next_step){
        die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($db_connection->error));    
    }
    header('Location: redirect somewhere');
    exit();

    //Close the STMT Connection         
    $stmt->close(); 
}
```

I have tried passing the $mysqli variable into the functions but that does not work. And tried adding the Defines into the function as well and passing them into variables themselves with no luck either. If I don't get a blank page It just dies at the prepare and says 'Failed Execution'. I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `die("Failed Execution");` with the below code..

```
$stmt = $db_connection->prepare($sql) or die($db_connection->error); //<-- Assuming $db_connection is a valid MYSQLi connection..
```

If you are providing your own customized error messages, it will be hard to find out the error.

Comment: Table 'database_name.members' doesn't exist. is the error I receive. Which I know is not true as it works fin when I keep the function in register.php. Would I need to place the DEFINE variables into the function itself?

Comment: Are you sure that the table `members` exist in that database ? Can you do a double-check on that ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out, I am building this application through a wordpress child theme. The problem was that most of my defined variables had the same name as those in the wp-config.php so It was always looking in the wrong place with the wrong credentials and such. Changes those and it works fine. Thank you for you all your help especially with the error reporting that is what saved me. thanks again